# What is the difference between .a and .so file?

Tags: libraries

As far as I understand they are libraries, but what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Related post - [What's the difference between .so, .la and .a library files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12237282/465053)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A `.a` file is a static library, while a `.so` file is a shared object (dynamic) library similar to a DLL on Windows. There's some detailed information about the differences between the two on **[this page](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)**.

Comment: `.a` can only be included as part of a program during compiling.  `.so`'s can be "imported" while a program loads.

Comment: what does .a stand for?

Comment: @hfrmobile The a stands for *archive* - a static library is a collection of object files created using the `ar` utility. [More info here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/static-libraries.html)

Answer (score 37):

As a follow on, a .a file is an "ar" archive. Not unlike a tar archive, it stores .o or object files, allowing them to be pulled out of the archive, and linked into a program, among other things. You could use ar to store other files if you wanted.

You can get a listing of the members of an ar file with the -t parameter, for instance:

```
ar -t /usr/lib/libc.a
```

A .so file is a "shared object" file, and has a lot more information available to the linker so that members can be linked in to a loading program as rapidly as possible.

For instance, try:

```
objdump -T /lib/libc-2.11.1.so
```

(or whatever version of libc.so you have in your /lib directory.) Note that a .so file could also just contain a linker script directing it to find the file elsewhere, or use something else.

Interestingly, a .so file can also be a full fledged program. For instance, trying running */lib/libc.so.6*. (This works on my Ubuntu 20.04 system)

Comment: Typo. you mean to write `ar -t /usr/lib/libc.a`. Actually the `-` doesn't seem to be necessary in this case. Also `/lib/libc.so.6.` just prints some output. I don't know if I would call it a `full fledged program`.

Comment: It's a full fledged program in the sense that it has a main symbol for exec to find.

Comment: You can also run `ldd` on .so's, and it will show you what other libraries it uses.  Static will return with a message saying it's not a dynamic library.